# Learning the relationship between two frequency distributions (input/output of a system)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling

I have a black-box system where X is the input and Y is the output, X and Y are random variables. I know the frequency distribution (the histogram) of both X and Y, but I don’t know which instance x_i of X produced which instance y_j of Y. I only know which input batch produced which output batch. Is there a way to learn the relationship between the input and the output of the system so that I can predict the output distribution given a new input distribution?

[image: Illustration of question]

Background: What I am trying to solve is the following: I can sample the mechanical properties of our raw material (input) and I can sample the mechanical strength of the finished product (output) but I don’t have a traceability of which raw material was used in which product, our batch process can’t handle this